# Flatten a (x,y) matrix to (xy,) vector using numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix, vector

I would like to flatten the below matrix so that it is a vector in the form of (xy,). I have tried using the reshape method but it is giving me a vector of (xy,1)

```
Matrix2 = np.array(Matrix2)

rows2, cols2 = Matrix2.shape

Matrix2 = np.reshape(rows2*cols2,1)
```

I know that arange will give me the desired dimension, but it is not holding the values in the matrix.

Comment: `Matrix2.flatten()` ?

Comment: Omit the `1` in the reshape if you don't want it.  Read the docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html  See also `ravel`